# Updating output file

Tags: c++, output

The program should then access/create a report file (called output.txt) where the result of this calculation will be saved.
Notice that if the “output.txt” file already exists then the program should just append the existing data by adding the result of this calculation.

```
while(choice==1){
int choice1;
        menu();
        cin>>choice1;
        cout<<endl;

        if (choice1==2){
            int num, counter=0;
            int node=0;
            cout<<"Please give the node you are looking for: ";
            cin>>node;

            for (num=0;num<arcs;num=num+2){
                if (node==tail[num]) {
                    counter++;

                }
            }
                cout<<"There are "<<counter<<" arcs leaving node "<<node;
            cout<<endl;
            outfile.open("output.txt");
            if(outfile.is_open()){
                outfile<<"There are "<<counter<<" arcs leaving node "<<node<<endl;

            }
outfile.close();//when I choose option 2 again it replaces the previous one   
cout<<"Report stored in file: output.txt."<<endl<<endl;
```

when I choose option 2 a second time the previous output is replaced by the new one.

Comment: open the file in append mode.

Answer (score 0):

This should add text to the end of your file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;


int main() {

 fstream addtext;

addtext.open ("testdoc.txt", fstream::in | fstream::out | fstream::app);

addtext<<"testTestTest"<<endl;

addtext.close();
            return 0;
        }
```

Comment: Using this didn't update the file just put the same output twice.

Comment: If you copy the code above into a new project you will see that this code works. It will create a txt file called testdoc.txt and write "testTestTest" in the document. If you change the "testTestTest" portion it will create another line below that with the new text.

Comment: @McCormick32 The problem the OP probably faces is that it's not possible to _insert_ or _update_ records to the file, rather than just append some ...

Comment: @user3413456 You'll need to have an in memory representation of the whole file (by means of your data records). You read in the file, when your program starts, you manage the records in memory, you save all the records, when requested, or automatically after inserting new or updating existing records.

Comment: I suppose "updating" was the wrong verbiage. Appending the file is what I need to do but don't know how.

Comment: 'output.txt' needs to hold each "There are __ arcs leaving node __" after the user enters a different node.